# 2 way data binding didn't works in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

In my angular 2 application i tried to bind view data using ngmodel,but it didnt works as i expected.

**event.component.html**

```
 <div  class="form-group">
     <label for="comment">About Us:</label>
         <input type="text" name="aboutus" class="form-control" 
 [(ngModel)]="home.aboutus" required placeholder="aboutus"/>{{home.aboutus}}

 </div>
```

**homemenu.ts**

```
  export class Home {
  aboutus: string;
    }
```

**eventcomponent.ts**
    
     `export class EventComponent {
     home:Home;
                          }
     constructor() { 
                  }`

Comment: because home is undefined

Comment: `constructor(){}` must be inside class `EventComponent`

Comment: @Ajith V Manali what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its always good idea to initialise class variables in constructor like this

```
export class EventComponent {
   home:Home = null; // or home:Home; 
   constructor() { 
        this.home = new Home()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be just **`aboutus`**

```
  <input type="text" name="aboutus" class="form-control" 
 [(ngModel)]="aboutus" required placeholder="aboutus"/>{{aboutus}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize home in event component.ts:

```
export class EventComponent {
       home:Home = new Home(); 
       constructor() { }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `home` is not initialized that's why `home.aboutus` is not bind with html template.

Try Below Code

```
export class EventComponent {
    home:Home;

    constructor() {
        this.home = new Home();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

bind the home instance property instead and bind [(ngModel)]="home.aboutus" spit the entered value using string interpolation {{home.aboutus}}.

```
export class EventComponent{
      home: Home;
      constructor() {
        this.home = new Home();
      }
}
```